# Scrolling UITableView to bottom while loading more data causes bounce to stop abruptly

Tags: uitableview

In short: How you achieve smooth `UITableView` animation when loading more content from a remote service?

In long:

I have a method in `tableView:willDisplayCell` that determines when to page for more content. When content is fetched, a footer view is added to my `UITableView` and a `UIActivityIndicator` is presented. Everything works great if my fetched content is returned AFTER the `UITableView` bounce animation stops.

However, there is a semi-edge case that happens when scrolling does not necessarily reach the bottom to trigger a bounce but it is far enough toward the bottom to trigger more data to be fetched. As the `UITableView` is gradually slowing, the data is returned, `UITableView` is reloaded, which then abruptly stops the natural deceleration of the `UITableView`.

I can add a dispatch_after to guarantee that the `UITableView` is reloaded after the bounce animation has completed but then there is always an abrupt stop as "Loading" footer is displayed when scrolling as the content is fetched.

I've also tried to add a block method that reloads my content after `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` is called but it still doesn't work quite right.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I got it to work, I guess the paging should trigger when we are at the bottom of the cell AFTER the bounce has stopped.

```
- (void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{    
    // only fetch when we are at the very bottom after bounce has stopped
    float scrollYPosition = scrollView.contentOffset.y + CGRectGetHeight(scrollView.frame);
    if((scrollYPosition >= scrollView.contentSize.height) && !self.noMoreData && !self.isFetching){
        [self fetchData];
    }
}
```